# Impossible to manage castle

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I am playing as a vassal of one of the kings and I had 1 village that was possible to manage (build in it). I captured a castle and got it awarded as my fief by the king, when I go to the castle there is the banner flying ower the castle scene etc. and I get 1000 income per week from it. However, I am unable to do any management except garrison management (move units to and from). Is this a feature of this game, am I doing something wrong, or is it just bugged?

Comment: It's possible the castle is already fully upgraded. With a fully upgraded castle there is nothing to manage.

Comment: Is there any way to check it?

Comment: What is the exact message you get when you enter the castle (the message that states who's banner is present)?

Comment: "As you approach, you are spotted by the castle guards, who welcome you and open the gates for their lord!" and then "You are at Haringoth Castle. Your own banner flies ower the gastle gate."

Comment: But I have now notticed, that on the map, when I hold mouse ower my castle, it says it is "under siege", however I can go from it and to it, and there are not enemy troops. Might this be the problem? And if it is, is there any way to get rid of this "under siege"?

Comment: Hmm... I thought when you approach the gates of a castle it'll tell you if it has a messenger post and/or a prisoner tower (the only 2 upgrades for a castle). If it has both it's fully upgraded. As for being under siege, you can rest in your castle for a day or two and see if anyone shows up. I recall having the same issue where an attacking army retreated as I approached my castle, but it was still listed as "under siege" for about a day (in game) after.

Answer (score 4):

You have basically answered you question in a comment, but **Yes, you cannot manage your castle because it is under siege**.

Screenshots (they are towns, but mechanic is the same. "Manage Castle/Town" button doesn't disappear even if all the improvements are built)

1. [Yalen without siege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52GRd.jpg) / [Inside the city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIGTZ.jpg) ("Manage this town." option is just above "Manage the garrison")
2. [Yalen buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kt2R.jpg) ("Manage this town." is still there even though all available buildings are built)
3. [Yalen under siege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3b8l.jpg) / [Inside the city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXcKM.jpg) (notice the absence of "Manage this town." option)

As for the siege itself, if there are no besiegers nearby (because the castle/town was taken, they escaped or were defeated), "Under Siege" should disappear after few hours.